# Does Fisher's exact test give any answers about proportions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I have a table that looks like this:

| initial | final | fsa_top | hours_top | fsa_bot | hours_bot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 2020-06 | 1540.33 | 35222.21 | 984.5 | 28765.22 |
| 2020-02 | 2020-07 | 1765.43 | 36782.99 | 976.22 | 27666.07 |

and so on

I want to perform a test to compare the proportions `fsa_top / hours_top`  to `fsa_bot / hours_bot`  and I have been explicitly asked to use **Fisher's test**. But the only Fisher's test I know is Fisher's exact test, which makes use of a contingency table where one column is the chance of 'success' and the other is 'failure' between the two groups.

What I did was, for the first row of the dataset (the interval 2020-01 to 2020-06):

|  | fsa | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| top | 1540.33 | 35222.21 |
| bot | 984.5 | 27666.07 |

And I run the fisher's test: `odds, p_fisher = stats.fisher_exact(contingency_table)`

Does it make any sense? Does Fishe's exact test tests for proportions or do I need another test?

My aim is to test if the proportions `fsa_bot / hours_bot`  and `fsa_top / hours_top` are comparable. The data for `bot` comes from the data for `top`, that is they are a subset. What I want is to anser the question: *does the ratio `fsa_bot/hours_bot` for the subset are comparable, or statistically significant, in some sense to the whole data?*. that is, if I compare the hours of the whole data to a subset taken from it, can I say that this subset differs from the set it came from?

the data are about absenteeism hours per six months in a big company, say X, which owns companies A, B and C, and I want to test if the absenteeism in A are comparable to the absenteeism in the whole X (which is A and B and C together).

**Edit**

Another way that came to my mind is:

The variable `fsa` has values 0 and values greater than zero. Thus I took the subset where it is zeroes and where it greater than zero and like:

```
for comp in company:

    heads = df.loc[df['fsa'] > 0]
    tails = df.loc[df['fsa] == 0]
    # it gives me the number of 'heads' in n trials:
    proportion = len(heads)/(len(heads)+len(tails))

    #Now for the subset:
    heads_emp = heads[heads['Company'] == comp]
    tails_emp = tails.loc[tails['Empresa'] == emp]
    total = len(heads_emp) + len(tails_emp)

    contingency_table = [[len(heads), len(tails)],
                         [len(heads_emp), len(tails_emp)]]
    
    odds, p_fisher = stats.fisher_exact(contingency_table)
    
    # And for a binomial test:
    result = stats.binomtest(k=len(heads_emp), n=total, p=proportion, alternative='two-sided')
```

Does it seems more reasonable now? Are those two tests applied the way they supposed to?

Comment: This test is inapplicable: it is for *counts,* not total quantities.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I thought so, that's why I came here. But I know little about statistics yet so it is hard to me to argue on how it is not right. I edited my question with another idea. If you can read it and help, I would appreciate

Comment: Start at the beginning and tell us what your numbers mean and how they were measured or created.

Comment: It could be tempting to cast this as a count problem by treating every hour/minute/second as a trial and counting up the number of "fsa" intervals, but the issue then is that trials are not independent as assumed by the Fisher test.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie why it would not be independent? In my edit, this is exactly what I tried to do: count the number of lines in the dataset where `fsa` was zero and greater than zero (that is, heads and tails) and used a binomial test to get the p-value under the assumption that the number of heads in the subcompany was equal to the proportion of heads in the whole big company. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: In the Fisher test (and related tests of counts), a count of $n$ represents $n$ independent observations.  In your case, a value of $n$ (for total duration?) could represent anywhere from $1$ through an arbitrarily large number of independent observations.  That's a fundamental distinction that precludes your application of count tests to these data.

Comment: @Dimitri I suppose they could be, I'd have to know more to be sure. But the use of "hours" here implies that the underlying data are really *durations*, which are usually non-independent over arbitrary time scales. At the hour scale, is an hour any more likely to be "fsa" if the previous hour was also "fsa"? What about the minute or second scale? At arbitrarily small time slices, being "fsa" in one moment may strongly imply that the previous and following moments were also "fsa", meaning the trials are not independent.

Comment: I see, but what if I count the number of fsa > 0 and fsa = 0 like that: fsa is absenteeism, or that is how many hours the employee did not showed up to work; if I count not the total hours, but len(fsa == 0) and len(fsa > 0) I would have a simple count of how many times an employee was absent from work in that interval. That is, in 100 observations, if 60 employess was absent and 40 not, I would simply have trials=100 and 'heads'=60, I could run a binomial test (and a fisher's exact test) having those data, right?

Comment: I would also have the count for the whole company, and could use it as the p for the binomial test.

In that case, this is like testing the proportions of heads in a coin (the subcompany) against the proportions of heads in another coin (the whole big company).

Comment: @Dimitri Still not quite clear how intervals are related or if they're independent. If you're looking at a single workday/week and want to see the proportion of the 100 employees that went absent, those should be reasonably independent since one person being absent does not affect another being absent (although even that wouldn't be strictly true if absenteeism is due to a disease outbreak, for example). But if you count the number of times one employee was absent in a week, those are less independent since sick days tend to be sequential (absentee days typically fall back-to-back).